# How can I get Java EE v5.0 to work with WAS 6.1?

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-6.1, java-ee-5

How can I get Java EE v5.0 to run on Webpshere Application Server 6.1? My coworker is able to run EAR 5.0 projects, but the highest version I can use is 1.4. I need to be able to use EAR version 5.0

Thanks.

For the record we are both using IBM RAD 7.5.5 - she is on a windows 7 computer and I am on a windows 8 machine.

I tried installing a feature pack to WAS 6.1 but it didn't seem to help out at all.

Comment: Usually, app servers supporting JEE6 have a whole lotta different libraries than those supporting JEE5. Coexistence is higly unlikely. Sometimes the same frameworks, but absolutely most of the times different versions of them (what would cause some `ClassNotFoundException`s and, at a lower level, `ClassCastExceptions`s).

Answer (score 3):

[You can't](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rovr_specs.html). I don't know what your coworker is doing, but she is not running JEE5 under WAS 6.1.